# Django foreign key vs complex query

Tags: django, django-models

I have a following Model:

```
class Library(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    library_id = models.ForeignKey(Library)
    author_id = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

1. How do I get a list of Authors who's books are in a specific library?
2. Is it more efficient in Author to have a foreign key directly to Library?

Comment: What do you mean by authors that belong to a specific library? Books belong to libraries, so having a FK in `Book` is totally fine. But authors? Are you sure about this?

Comment: why would an author be specific to a library

Comment: I want to get a list of Authors who's books are in the library. It's just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of Authors who's Books are in a particular Library by using [reverse lookups across the Foreign Key relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

```
some_library = Library.objects.get(0)
authors_in_library = Author.objects.filter(book__library_id=some_library)
```

You should not add an `library` field to the Author. This is premature optimization and will complicate things because you'll need to update two relationships instead of one if a book is moved to a new library. You'll have to make said update in a transaction as well. Unless you are facing significant measurable performance issues, don't even consider this.

**Additionally**, do NOT add `_id` suffixes to your fields. They're treated as actual object relationships in Django. It will also conflict with the fact that [Django adds its own `_id` to foreign keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#database-representation) for doing id-only lookups. Your query should read as follows, without the `_id`:

```
Author.objects.filter(book__library=some_library)
```

Comment: Your query will return a list of libraries, not authors.

Comment: You're right, somewhere along the line I got your needs mixed up. Fixing...

Comment: Thanks! Is it worth adding a library key to Authors to make less complicated queries? Or is it better to have less keys in models and do complex queries?

Comment: No, it will make things more complicated since now you'll have to update two relationships whenever you change a book's library. A reverse relationship is not a complicated query, it's a simple join.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an explanation of why this is a bad idea.